# Can I prove this combinatorial relation using induction on $k$? $\sum\limits_{i = 0}^{k} \binom{n + i}{i} = \binom{n + k + 1}{k}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Or must I prove this via induction on $n$?

My idea is to simply use the identity $\binom{n + 1}{k} = \binom{n}{k - 1} + \binom{n}{k}$ as follows

$$\sum\limits_{i = 0}^{k} \binom{n + i}{i} = \binom{n + k + 1}{k}$$
$$\sum\limits_{i = 0}^{k + 1} \binom {n + i}{i} = \binom{n + k + 1}{k} + \binom{n + k + 1}{k + 1}$$
$$\sum\limits_{i = 0}^{k + 1} \binom {n + i}{i} = \binom{n + k + 2}{k + 1}$$

but I'm not sure if this is valid and I'd like an explanation for why I should choose one over the other.

Comment: You shouldn't write the thing you are proving at the start. Also, you need to prove a base case for induction to work here.

Comment: As for the question of if you should do induction over $n$ or induction over $k$, the answer is that you should be doing *double-induction over both*

Comment: What exactly is double-induction? I can't find any mention of this on the internet